# Change called Controller at runtime in Cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to halt the action performed by the user if it is not authorized.
So i decided to write a function in `AppController` and call it in `beforeFilter()` function like This

```
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        $this->requestData = $this->request->data;

        if (isset($this->request->params['prefix']) && $this->request->params['prefix'] == 'api/v1') {
            $this->checkAuthToken(); // My function to check authentication

        }

        parent::beforeFilter($event);

    }
```

My function to check authentication

```
    public function checkAuthToken()
    {

        if (empty($this->request->header('AUTH-TOKEN')) || empty($this->requestData['employee_id'])) {
                $this->DATA['error'] = 'Access Denied. Contact admin';
                $this->DATA['error_code'] = 2;
        } else {
            $this->loadModel('Employees');
            $employee = $this->Employees->get($this->requestData['employee_id']);

            if ($employee->status == 'B') {
                $this->DATA['error'] = 'Your account is blocked. Contact admin';
                $this->DATA['error_code'] = 3;
            } else if ($employee->status == 'I') {
                $this->DATA['error'] = 'Your account is not active yet. Contact Admin';
                $this->DATA['error_code'] = 4;
            } else if ($employee->auth_token != $this->request->header('AUTH-TOKEN')) {
                $this->DATA['error'] = 'Access Denied! Invalid Request';
                $this->DATA['error_code'] = 5;

            } else if ($employee['fail_attempts'] > 3) {
                $this->DATA['error'] = 'Due to so many attempts you account is blocked! Contact admin';
                $this->DATA['error_code'] = 6;

            }
        }
    }
```

After this in `beforeRender`

```
    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {

        $debugApi = true;
        if (!$debugApi) {
            if (isset($this->DATA['error_debug'])) {
                $this->log($this->DATA['error_debug']);
                $this->DATA['error'] = 'Something went wrong! Please try again';
            }
        }
        $this->set('data', $this->DATA);

        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }

    }
```

What is going wrong is if a user request for the API and my authentication gives error then i have to halt calling the controller action and give him error message. Or if i can change the controller to blank one.

Thanks

Comment: You are not organizing your code properly. Cakephp has a way to creating custom auth http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects

Comment: I cant because its for rest api and we are not using session in it so i have to check the user authentication every time. Its like login every time when the user hit the url

Comment: If anyone can give an idea how to halt calling the controller if the authentication  fails.

Comment: Actually, you could. As documented, the auth layer can handle [**stateless authentication**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-stateless-authentication-systems) too, which can also be figured from the fact that it ships with Basic auth support out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [setAction](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-another-action-on-the-same-controller) method if authentication fails. Something like:

```
if ($this->DATA['error']) {
  return $this->setAction('error_method');
}
```

Comment: `setAction` is for "Redirecting to Another Action on the Same Controller" which i don't want. I want to change the controller too

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->DATA['error']) {
  $this->redirect(['controller'=>'test', 'action'=>'/']);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: If i redirect to another controller then the error message `this->DATA['error']` will not be set after the redirection and i have to make a condition to neglect the authentication for the test controller to stop it for the infinite redirection